# How to convert `c('a','b')` to `cbind(a,b)` in R formula?

Tags: r

```
myfun<-function(c('a','b'),c('g'),df){
    manova(cbind(a,b)~g,data=df)
}
myfun(c('Sepal.Length','Sepal.Width'),c('Species'),iris)
```

If I want to make `myfun(c('Sepal.Length','Sepal.Width'),c('Species'),iris)` to get `manova` result,I need to revise `myfun`.

I tried but failed:

```
myfun<-function(var,group,df){
    manova(as.formula(cbind(print(var,quote = FALSE))~group),data=df)
}
```

I don't know how to convert  `c('a','b')` to `cbind(a,b)`,any thought?
Thanks for any answer in advance.

Comment: Use `paste` .  When you create the function, why you are quoting the arguments

Comment: The c() function generates a vector from atomic elements only.  If you want to pass a collection of other types of objects use a list.  e.g `my_list <- list(df$field1, df$field2) f(my_list, ...)`

Comment: `sprintf` would be useful, `as.formula(sprintf('cbind(%s, %s) ~ %s', 'a', 'b', 'group'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a `formula` with `paste`

```
myfun <- function(colnms1, group, dat) {
       fmla <- as.formula(paste0("cbind(", 
         paste(colnms1, collapse=","), ")", " ~ ", group))
       mva <- manova(fmla, data = dat)
       mva$call <- fmla
       mva


 }

myfun(c('Sepal.Length','Sepal.Width'), 'Species' ,iris)
#Call:
#   cbind(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) ~ Species

#Terms:
#                 Species Residuals
#Sepal.Length    63.21213  38.95620
#Sepal.Width     11.34493  16.96200
#Deg. of Freedom        2       147

#Residual standard errors: 0.5147894 0.3396877
#Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61793558/how-to-convert-ca-b-to-parameter-of-tablea-b

Comment: I am not sure is there a general solution?