# How to convert `c(a,b)` to parameter of `table(a,b)`?

Tags: r

I need to write function `vec_to_para`,when I run   `vec_to_para(c('vs','gear'),mtcars)`,should output result of `with(mtcars,table(vs,gear))`.

I asked a [similar quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61783029/how-to-convert-ca-b-to-cbinda-b-in-r-formula) yesterday,then I tried `paste()`

```
#expected result
> with(mtcars,table(vs,gear))
   gear
vs   3  4  5
  0 12  2  4
  1  3 10  1

#my function,where is the problem?
>vec_to_para<-function(vec,df){
    with(df,tables(paste(vec,collapse=',')))
}

#run to test function
>vec_to_para(c('vs','gear'),mtcars)
vs,gear 
      1
```

Where is the problem of `vec_to_para` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```
vec_to_para<-function(vec,df) {
  table(df[vec])
}

vec_to_para(c("vs", "gear"), mtcars)
   gear
vs   3  4  5
  0 12  2  4
  1  3 10  1
```

However, using `get()` you can make your current solution work with minimal modifications:

```
vec_to_para<-function(vec,df) {
  with(df, table(get(vec[1]), get(vec[2])))
}

vec_to_para(c("vs", "gear"), mtcars)

     3  4  5
  0 12  2  4
  1  3 10  1
```

Comment: Why `paste(vec,collapse=',')` not workable in `table()`? I didn't find a general solution.

Comment: It's complicated, essentially you are just passing a character vector to table instead of an expression to be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `eval` + `parse` in function `vec_to_para`, e.g.,

```
vec_to_para<-function(vec,df){
    with(df,eval(parse(text = sprintf("table(%s)",toString(vec)))))
}
```

such that

```
> vec_to_para(c('vs','gear'),mtcars)
   gear
vs   3  4  5
  0 12  2  4
  1  3 10  1
```